# Mobile data offline or timeout whereas hotspot just works

Tags: mobile-network

How can I troubleshoot the following situation:

- during mobile data my phone often is experiencing 100% time outs (ERR_TIMED_OUT) or Chrome states it is offline
- whereas my connected laptop through hotspot is not experiencing any issues

My phone states full connectivity and 4g being present.

This leads to my hypothesis that some configuration or malicious app is flooding the local network stack on my phone.

Is there a way to diagnose this further? I really want to get my mobile data connectivity back!

Phone: Lenovo P2. 
OS: Android 7.

**Edit 15-09-2019**
I have reset my phone to factory settings but to no avail. The issue still remains. I also swapped SIM cards with another phone. No effect. The second SIM in my phone does not solve the issue. And my SIM in another phone just works correctly over there.

**Edit 16-09-2019**
Interestingly, apps that have lots of patience (long time-out policy), such as my mobile park app, and apparently WhatsApp as well, are still able to send and receive data.

Comment: Is your phone rooted? Using any firewall app? Using any VPN app? Can you ping some IP address on internet e.g. `1.1.1.1`?

Comment: No my phone isn't rooted. How to confirm? Maybe there is a firewall app installed. How do I know? Pinging 1.1.1.1 also results into timeout / offline.